# Mixing StateT and MonadUnliftIO

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, monad-transformers

I'm not sure on the best name for my question, but I seem to have coded myself into a corner somewhat. Or at least I am faced with a slightly awkward design descision within my hspec test suite for my project.

My project has to make some third party API calls, and in HSpec I am trying to make it so these can be faked using a transformer implemented using `StateT`, that can be placed inside a test stack to enable the ability to 'fake' these API calls. I always want to stub these calls out in unit tests, I never want to hit the real API, ever.

The way I am 'stubbing' calls is by defining all of my systems effects with typeclasses and providing a different instance when in test. So for example I would have a class like:

```
class FireApiGetRequest m where
  fireApiGetRequest :: GetRequest -> m (Either ApiError GetReponse)

instance FireApiGetRequest Hander where
  fireApiGetRequest = -- real world implementation
```

I have two transformer stacks for my tests currently one is known as `AppTestIO`, and `AppTestPureM`.

`AppTestIO` is made up of a `ReaderT` that contains a connection pool to a real test database and some test configuration settings, and `AppTestPureM` is a type alias for `StateT FakeDatabaseCalls Gen`, much in the same way as I write out the API calls with typeclasses, database calls are also factored out into type classes and 'stubbed' out in the same way. This works well, only I would like to add a transformer layer to both stacks, that mocks the third party API. In my mind I should be able to define a transformer that can sit within both of these transformer stacks and give me the ability to fake these API calls:

```
type AppTestPureM = StateT FakedDatabaseCalls (ThirdPartyApiMocksT Gen)

type AppTestIO = ThirdPartyApiMocksT (AppTestT IO)

newtype AppTestT m a = AppTestT
  { unAppTestT :: ReaderT TestEnv m a
  }
```

On the face of it this seems like a great idea because it means I can stub out these API calls regardless of whether or not the test is hitting the real database, basically.

For the instances, I have no issue defining instances for the API calls in test:

```
instance FireApiGetRequest ThirdPartyApiMocksT where
  fireApiGetRequest = -- test implementation, access state and return value based on that

instance FireApiGetRequest m => FireApiGetRequest (StateT s m) where
  fireApiGetRequest = lift . fireApiGetRequest
```

And I can define helper functions in my test to get the instances to return the fake data that I want:

```
stubApiGetRequest :: Monad m => (Either ApiError GetResponse) -> ThirdPartyApiMocksT m ()
stubApiGetRequest returnVal = undefined -- store `returnVal` in the state for use in typeclass instance
```

My issue arises when I actually start using these instances within my tests. For those functions in my app that hit the database (that aren't yet stubbed out with typeclass instances), they ultimately are using `runSqlPool`, which uses `MonadUnliftIO`, and `MonadUnliftIO` is effectively forbidding me from mixing these together.

The approach to achieve 'state' while using `MonadUnliftIO` is to use `ReaderT` + `MVar` instead. I don't have a huge issue with this normally, my only problem here is that my `PureM` stack is based around `StateT`, and also does not run in `IO`, because it is used to run 'effectful' computations using fake data in order to write the test in a pure way, with no IO. This also means I can use `quickcheck` to test these functions if that is something I want to do. I am aware there is `quickcheck-monadic` so having these functions result in `IO` may not be the end of the world, but I would like retain `AppTestPureM a -> Gen a`. Using `ReaderT` + `MVar` here in this situation would make it so that these tests then depend on `IO`. So these two test stacks are contradictory.

I suppose that illustrates the situation I am in now. I am not sure how exactly to proceed from here.

Comment: Try using `MonadState` interface instead of `StateT`, this way for pure setting you can continue using `StateT`, while for the computation that does require `IO` you can use something like  `RIO`, which already has a `MonadState` instance ( or roll out your own using `IORef`, you don't need `MVar` for this.)

Comment: Can you provide type for that `runSqlPool` ?